# AES encryption and decryption in ASP

Tags: c#

I'm developing an app written by C# and UWP(Universal Windows Platform).
here is my code for UWP :

```
    public string AES_Encrypt(string input, string pass)
    {
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
        CryptographicKey AES;
        HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
        CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();

        string encrypted = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] hash = new byte[32];
            Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
            byte[] temp;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);

            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);

            AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));

            IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            encrypted = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(AES, Buffer, null));

            return encrypted;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public string AES_Decrypt(string input, string pass)
    {
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
        CryptographicKey AES;
        HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
        CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();

        string decrypted = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] hash = new byte[32];
            Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
            byte[] temp;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);

            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);

            AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));

            IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(input);
            byte[] Decrypted;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(AES, Buffer, null), out Decrypted);
            decrypted = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypted, 0, Decrypted.Length);

            return decrypted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly but I have to write an decryption for ASP just like this but I don't know how can I write this in ASP because these codes doesn't work on ASP.

I would appreciate it if you help me. 
Thanks

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption.

Comment: Are you talking about ASP or ASP.Net?  They are very different things.

Comment: Zaph I really don't understand decryption or encryption , It's to hard to understand.  AMY ASP.NET,